# glGenVertexArraysOES returns a zero VAO on iOS, sometimes

Tags: iphone, ios6, ios-simulator, opengl-es-2.0

I have a problem with the creation of VAOs on iOS. Sometimes it works just fine, and glGenVertexArraysOES returns a non-zero VAO via the second argument, but other times, it simply returns zero and no error via glGetError()

I have two cases. One works, the other doesn't. They're both in initialisation code, and they're both more or less the same code:

Working:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &m_vertexBufferObject);
errorCheck();

GLuint vao = 0;
glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &vao);
errorCheck();
glBindVertexArrayOES(vao);
errorCheck();

(vao set up goes here)

(vao != 0)
```

Not working:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArrayOES(0);

errorCheck();
GLuint vao = 0;
glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &vao);
errorCheck();
glBindVertexArrayOES(vao);
errorCheck();

(vao == 0)
```

The glBind* functions in the non-working block are largely just an attempt to fix the problem by mitigating any previously bound state. It didn't help.

The code is multi-threaded. I have one context, and only one thread is permitted to use it at one time by way of a mutex. When a thread acquires the context, I lock the mutex and call setCurrentContext. I restore the current context to nil afterwards. I believe this should be an acceptable multi-threading setup from what I've read elsewhere. In any case, disabling threading and running everything on the same thread makes no difference!

The successful case happens right at the start, at initialisation time. That works fine... the other case happens during loading time, whilst a render loop is going on (but still being marshalled by said critical sections and context assignments), and that's the case that fails.

I'm basically assuming there must be some sort of precondition to glGenVertexArrayOES's execution that isn't being met. I don't think it's really the body of the VAO set up in the latter case, I think it's something that happens between the successful initial VAO setups, and the later attempted set ups.

It fails on both the sim and the phone, so there's clearly something going on... yet, it's a silent error, so it's giving me no angle to investigate. It works just fine on OpenGL for OS X. Furthermore, attempts to replicate the error or similar conditions (eg, the threading in various pieces of sample code have failed.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I should add, that the same code works on OS X (albeit with the OES suffixes stripped)

Comment: Is the code that precedes the failing glGentVertexArraysOES do a full creation and init of a VAO, followed by setting the buffer and VAO to 0? If so, you want to comment out the glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0) line, and perhaps by unbinding it is messing up the VAO flow in GL. I've found if unbind the ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER before I unbind the VAO that VAO nor any of my scene will not be usable. Its a hunch, not an answer, hence the comment (loosly related link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545479/why-does-binding-a-gl-element-array-buffer-to-0-produce-a-memmove-error)

Comment: Hello,

What happens is that the working case happens at start up, then we get into a loop where we're doing rendering (which is what I suspect pollutes any preconditions for GenVertexArray), then the other one fails.

So yes, VAOs do get created, and I bind a 0 VAO at the end.. but I don't unbind any buffers *before* I unbind the VAO (like in that link), which I believe it's what critical in this case.

The VAO creation is on a different thread to the render, but single threading the code makes no difference.

Also, I've tried to deliberately break sample code, but that sheds no light. :-(

Answer (score 1):

This is a class of view derived from GLKViewController.

```
@interface IncubeViewController : GLKViewController {
      ...
}
```

This is how I load vao:

```
- (void) loadGeometry
{
        /* Pieces */
        for (int i = ptFirst; i < ptLast; i++) {
                glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &pieceObject[i].array);
                glBindVertexArrayOES(pieceObject[i].array);

                glGenBuffers(1, &pieceObject[i].buffer);
                glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pieceObject[i].buffer);

                glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertextData[i].vertNumber * sizeof(Vertex),
                             vertextData[i].vertArray, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

                glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE,
                                      sizeof(Vertex), (void *)offsetof(Vertex, position));
                glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
                glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE,
                                      sizeof(Vertex), (void *)offsetof(Vertex, normal));
                glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
        }

        /* Cube */
        glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &cubeObject.array);
        glBindVertexArrayOES(cubeObject.array);

        glGenBuffers(1, &cubeObject.buffer);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeObject.buffer);

        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, CubeDataNumberOfVertices * sizeof(Vector3),
                     CubeData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
                              0, (void *)0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);

        /* Sphere */
        glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &sphereObject.array);
        glBindVertexArrayOES(sphereObject.array);

        glGenBuffers(1, &sphereObject.buffer);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sphereObject.buffer);

        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, SphereDataNumberOfVertices * sizeof(Vertex),
                     SphereData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
                              sizeof(Vertex), (void *)offsetof(Vertex, position));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
        glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
                              sizeof(Vertex), (void *)offsetof(Vertex, normal));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);

        /* Diagonal grid */
        glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &diagonalGridObject.array);
        glBindVertexArrayOES(diagonalGridObject.array);

        glGenBuffers(1, &diagonalGridObject.buffer);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, diagonalGridObject.buffer);

        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(diagonalGridData),
                     diagonalGridData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
                              sizeof(Vector3), (void *)0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);

        glBindVertexArrayOES(0);
}

- (void) unloadGeometry
{
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &diagonalGridObject.buffer);
        glDeleteVertexArraysOES(1, &diagonalGridObject.array);
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &cubeObject.buffer);
        glDeleteVertexArraysOES(1, &cubeObject.array);
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &sphereObject.buffer);
        glDeleteVertexArraysOES(1, &sphereObject.array);
        for (int i = ptFirst; i < ptLast; i++) {
                glDeleteBuffers(1, &pieceObject[i].buffer);
                glDeleteVertexArraysOES(1, &pieceObject[i].array);
        }
}
```

While it is not showing you're doing something wrong, I add it here just for ref if anyone needs it.

One explanation I have is that you're trying to create your vao in wrong moment of app init or init was not quite correct (for example, context is not set).

I have the following stack here:

```
- (void)setupGL
{
        [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];

        self.effect = [[[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init] autorelease];
        if (self.effect) {
                self.effect.useConstantColor = GL_TRUE;
                self.effect.colorMaterialEnabled = GL_TRUE;
                self.effect.light0.enabled = GL_TRUE;
                self.effect.light0.diffuseColor = GLKVector4Make(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        }

        ((GLKView *)self.view).drawableMultisample = GLKViewDrawableMultisample4X;
        self.pauseOnWillResignActive = YES;
        self.resumeOnDidBecomeActive = YES;
        self.preferredFramesPerSecond = 30;

        glDisable(GL_DITHER);
        glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glLineWidth(2.0f);
        [self loadGeometry];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.context = [[[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2] autorelease];
        if (!self.context)
                NSLog(@"Failed to create ES context");

        GLKView *view = (GLKView *)self.view;
        view.context = self.context;
        view.drawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat24;

        [self setupGL];
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this gives me another reference example to dig through and compare against. It's often just a case of having the right example to find a salient difference :-) 

Will let you know if this turns up anything.

Comment: Further digging reveals that it's not so much the VAO creation that fails to return a non-zero ID, but the first thing to fail is glGenBuffers - it does nothing, but returns no error; it simply fails to return a value (though it does work ok the first time).

Comment: when do you load your vao? In my example it is done in viewDidLoad time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally cracked this.

It turns out, that I had some RAII-like code that would call setCurrentContext before and after some OpenGL ops on a thread. Crucially, it would [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:nil] when a scope ended... but these scopes could be nested, and it did that for every nested scope, not the last scope.

The upshot of that was that the current context was nil when OpenGL was called. The OpenGL calls would just "do nothing", and "do nothing" included "throw no errors" - you'd think glGetError() might have said something at least.

So, if you don't have a current context set, then it seems GL on the mac crashes, but GLES on IOS just early-outs with no error.